# What kind of latch would be best to continuously store and feed in a series of inputs?

Tags: integrated-circuit, flipflop, latch, function-generator

So I've got an assignment where I've two buttons and LED screen. One button inputs a '1' and the other a '0', and when four inputs are detected the screen displays the number eg. If I typed 0011 it would display 3. I've also been told the output has to only display two seconds before it stops, which I can do with D flip flops and clock cycle.

But now comes the tricky part. I'm supposed to make it so that if I keep entering inputs it keeps displaying them, like for example if I managed to key in '000100100011' in three seconds it has to display 1 for two seconds, 2 for two seconds and 3 for two seconds. There also has to be a gap of two seconds between them.

So now I'm kinda lost? I used this design earlier [image] for a circuit which only detects one input, but I don't think I can use it here. Do i use JK flip flops for this? Any help?

Comment: Image too blurry, can't read the text

Comment: I think the OP has presented a reasonable amount of effort there.  Perhaps key to the next step is that the output needs to display a digit based one one 4-bit word at a time but the circuit as a whole needs to store at least two more words or 8 bits, depending on how you want to store the data.  Choosing a suitable FIFO will determine what you need to do to get data in and out.

Comment: @Miron Sorry, that's all I'll saved. I describe the circuit instead.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely 3 parts to your system:

button signals
-> (serial in parallel out shift register) ->
4b number to  be inserted into FIFO,
signal for when a 4 digit sequence is finished, to insert item into FIFO
-> (FIFO buffer) <->
signal from state machine to FIFO for the next 4b number to be taken out,
the 4b number from the buffer,
a 'not empty' signal
<-> (state machine) ->
4b number for display

With the 2nd part of the requirement, they are asking you to use a 4 bit wide, at least 3 word deep, First-In-First-Out buffer, with an input signals for inserting numbers into it and taking numbers out, as well as a 'not empty' output for showing if the buffer contains any numbers.
There are FIFO chips like the 74HC40105 that do this for you, with "data-in-ready" and "data-out-ready" outputs to let you know when the buffer is not completely empty or not completely full.

The state machine will send a a signal to take out a number from the FIFO every couple of seconds while the 'not-empty' signal is high.

If you are not using a FIFO chip and instead making the FIFO yourself from simpler blocks (a much harder task), I would definitely start off prototyping inside a logic simulator like Logisim.

Comment: Yeah I'm supposed to make this out of simpler IC chips, but thanks for the help regardless!

Comment: Cool, a starting point could be to look at the 74HC40105 datasheet and try to replicate it's functionality

Answer (score 1):

There're very many ways to implement each part of the circuit, but the essential functions remain, no matter how you achieve them:

1. Button signal conditioning (debouncing).

   The button signals need to be debounced. [I'll assume you've looked it up](https://my.eng.utah.edu/%7Ecs5780/debouncing.pdf) and have a clean, debounced logic signal from each button, with valid LO and HI states.
2. Serial-in, parallel-out shift register memory.

   Such registers need a clock signal and data signal. When the clock transitions (usually LO to HI), the state of the data signal is shifted into one end of the register.

   The button signals (debounced!) can be OR-ed to form a clock: either button, when pressed, shifts the data into the shift register.

   Only one of the buttons is used as a D input: when you press that button, a 1 will be clocked in. When you press the other button, a zero will be clocked in, since that button only drives the clock, while the other button, inactive (0), drives the data.
3. A latch to store contents of the serial register for display - if needed.

   Such latches sometimes are integrated in the shift registers or display drivers, so it may not need to be a separate chip.
4. Binary-to-BCD decoder & LED driver.

   The parallel output from the shift register would go to two BCD-to-7 segment decoders that drive the displays.
5. Flashing/blanking circuit (can be integrated in the BCD decoder).
6. Clock source/timer for flashing or display duration limit.

   A 555 timer then disables the display to make it flash. Some decoders already provide a blanking signal, so no external circuitry is needed.

   A timer could also be used to make the display turn on for a certain time only after a full input digit (4 or 8 button presses, depending on your wishes) was detected. That would require:
7. A counter to detect groups of 4 or 8 button presses.

   That's if you need to e.g. enable display and latching only after so many button presses.

---

If I were to build such a thing from parts on hand, I'd be using CD4000 logic, since I have it available. I'm not suggesting you do it that way, just sharing how *I* would do it - and it's just one way out of very many, no one necessarily better or worse.

I'd use either CD4055, CD4056 or CD4511 for the binary-to-BCD decoder and driver, since it has a blanking input and can drive 7-segment displays directly. The 4056 and 4511 have a latch, but it wouldn't be used in this case.

A CD4094 could be used for a serial-in, parallel-out register. It has a bonus: an internal latch, so that the shifting and display update functions can be independent. In principle, you could add a counter that would count 8 button presses, and only update the display latch when 8 digits were shifted in. Or you could update every 4 digits.

Other options would be CD4015 and CD4035 - those are just shift registers without the additional latch.

For debouncing and miscellaneous logic, CD4093 schmitt-trigger NAND gates would work. You could fashion two-SR latches for debouncing from one of those, and use another one for the OR function. You could also OR with two diodes and a pull-down resistor, instead of a chip.

For counting button presses to have the "update on 4th/8th press" function, any of a number of counters would do, e.g. CD4022, CD4024, etc. There's very many others in the CD4000 series that would work.

A solution meeting your minimal requirements, but without counting button presses, using nothing but CD4000 chips and a few passive components, would take three (4) CD4xxx logic chips (same as MC14xxx) - a quadruple NOR/NAND gate, one shift register, two 7-segment decoders, a 555, and two 7-segment displays.

A button press counter used to trigger display/latching would be an extra CD4022 for example. Just one more chip. No other logic needed.

For CMOS logic, all unused inputs must be tied to a valid logic state, e.g. low.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8IM82.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This should give you some idea of how simple such a circuit can be. I've omitted the 555, since there's enough of those everywhere, and the particular component values you'd have to figure out yourself, etc.

Comment: Thanks! I'm likely using a different method since I'm not allowed to use 4055 chips but I appreciate the help

Comment: You can always do the BCD-to-7 segment decoding with discrete logic. Also note that this circuit has almost identical equivalents in any other logic family, e.g. TTL, 74HC, etc.